# Remove selector criteria in variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an online shop, with specific links to products *e.g.* (http://example.com/products/phones/nexus-5).

I'm using the following code,

```
var get_product_availability_classname = $("[class$='_availability']").attr('class');
```

which selects *(creates a variable with the value of)* the element that has a class ending in "_availability".

Every product page has a different piece of text just before the `_availability`, like `GOOGLENEXUS5_availability`, `SAMSUNG4KTV_availability`, `whatever_availability`...

**What I have to do** now is to essentially remove the criteria I used to get that whole class name (*i.e.* `class$='_availability'`); using the example above it'd be trimmed from `SAMSUNG4KTV_availability` to `SAMSUNG4KTV`.

### Possible solutions

I haven't figured how to, but we could use JavaScript's substring() or substr().

Comment: can you add sample html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be best off using Regex in this situation. The following will look for the _availability in the classes string and if it finds it it will capture what came before.

```
var get_product_availability_classname = $("[class$='_availability']").attr('class');

var matches = /([^\s]*)_availability\b/g.exec(get_product_availability_classname)

if(matches.length > 1){
    var your_id = matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I've got a new problem. If you can, [please solve it replying to this comment](http://notes.io/yz7P).

Comment: @alej27 Use `window[your_id + '_expected_availability_date']` to get the variable value

Answer (score 1):

Use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with a callback and update the class name using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) regex.

Although use [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) since there is a chance to have multiple classes, in that case, the class can be at the start or between two classes.

```
var get_product_availability_classname = $("[class*='_availability '],[class$='_availability']");

get_product_availability_classname.attr('class',function(i,v){
   return v.replace(/_availability\b/g,'');
});
```

```js
var get_product_availability_classname = $("[class*='_availability '],[class$='_availability']");

get_product_availability_classname.attr('class', function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/_availability\b/, '');
});

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="abc_availability"></div>
<div class="abc_availability class"></div>
<div class="class abc_availability"></div>
<div class="class abc_availability class1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there will only ever be a single `_` in the class name

```
var get_product_availability_classname = $("[class$='_availability']").attr('class')
.split(' ') // split the class to individual classes
.filter(function(cls) { // filter ones with _availability
    return cls.split('_').pop() == 'availability');
})[0]; // use first match
var product = get_product_availability_classname.split('_')[0]
```

`.split('_')` creates an array `["PRODUCT", "availability"]` and the `[0]` selects the first item of this array

alternatively you could also

```
var product = get_product_availability_classname.split('_availability')[0]
```

this does the same thing, except it splits on the string `_availability`, and it doesn't matter how many `_` in the prefix

Comment: This solution is wrong. It will only work in the case where the element only has one class. If there is a class before the availability class it will fail.

Comment: Fixed with an update to `get_product_availability_classname`

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always in the form x_y, where x and y don't contain an underscore, then you can use the split function to split on the underscore.

```
    var str = "SAMSUNG4KTV_availability";
    var result = str.split("_")[0];
    console.log(result);
```

The split function returns an array of strings containing the substring in between each underscore, you use [0] to select the first element in the array.